# Using Python how do i handle a VBA API asking for type 'object'

Tags: api, object, python-3.x, com, typeerror

I'm brand new to Python, I'm using 3.3.  I began to explore COM, and what you can do with it is incredible for an engineer.  I'm an engineering undergrad student, so I've got enough programming skills to get by, but I don't actually understand what I'm really doing.

The project I'm starting with has an excellent API help if I were writing in VBA, VB.NET, C# or C++ but I'm doing this project in Python and I'm two lines of code away from being done.  I'm struggling with the second last "Method" of the program.

the API help offers this VBA description of the Method I'm trying to access.

For VBA:

```
Dim instance As (a handle?? to the class??? of this method, I know I've got a proper object)
Dim NElementNumber As Integer
Dim NStepNum As Integer
Dim DispPlane As Object  (API says if you don't have a value to use, use Nothing, they literally type Nothing in in the provided examples)
Dim NUnits As Integer
Dim value As Object

value = instance.Method(NElementNumber, NStepNum, DispPlane, NUnits, ErrorCode)
```

and my python shell spits back to me

```
"Results = instance.Method(i,1,nothing,3,0)
 File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line2, in Method
TypeError: Objects of type 'object' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT"
```

so I'm confused because, I have an idea what the problem is, obviously somehow i need to make the other program see that 'Nothing' entry as an object like it's expecting.  But how do I go about doing that? what kind of Object are there many kinds of Objects?